# Firebase updates multiple children wrongly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application, I am using Firebase to store data. Everytime the users' location changes, a function is called to write the new coordinates to Firebase. However, I'm working with multiple accounts, and the program writes the information to the wrong child nodes. I cannot seem to find the problem. My code should make the situation clearer:

```
public void locationPusher(Location currentLocation) {
    if (currentLocation != null) {
        double lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
        double lon = currentLocation.getLongitude();

        Log.e("Lat: ", "" + lat);
        Log.e("Long: ", "" + lon);

        Double[] data = new Double[]{lat, lon};

        FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
        firebaseHelper.pushToFirebaseOnLocationUpdate(firebaseUser, data);
    }
}
```

The above code is the location pusher, that is called everytime the location changes. At the end, `pushToFirebaseonLocationUpdate` pushes this information to the correct user node, where `firebaseUser` is the current logged in user:

```
public void pushToFirebaseOnLocationUpdate(@NonNull FirebaseUser loggedInUser, Double[] data) {
    userRef = userDataRef.child(loggedInUser.getUid());

    userRef.child("location").child("latitude").setValue(data[0]);
    userRef.child("location").child("longitude").setValue(data[1]);
}
```

Somehow, however, when I log the user out and I log in with another account, the app sets the location nodes in the current user and in the user that was already logged out. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: The code writes data to the specific user's location under `userDataRef`. Without seeing how you initialize `firebaseUser` and `userDataRef` it's hard to say more than that you're likely caching a stale value for one of those.

Comment: The `userDataRef` is defined when the static method `FirebaseHelper` is called (just changed that in the code). The `firebaseUser` is initialized as `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`, which returns the correct user.

Comment: Please isolate the problem in a [single, minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your question to include this MCVE. Chances are that you'll find where you are caching the wrong user while building such an MCVE. One step to an MCVE is to use `userRef = userDataRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());` instead of the variable and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used `getUid()` just before I called the `pushToFirebaseOnLocationUpdate` and passed it as an argument instead of passing the `firebaseUser`, which helped!

Comment: Frank van Puffelen  You have he acceptable answer .Thank you . You saved my day !!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you are logging out that you clean the userRef variable.